# BackGroundTask windows phone 8.1 working not property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I use background task with time trigger of windows phone 8.1 for update information and save it to offline, create a tile for notification for use.

I use `Debug mode` for testing on Emulator then every thing is ok, but every thing begin when I use `Release mode` for build in lumia 820 for testing.

Task is registered ok. But when BackGround task run, it close after some minutes.

I know there are some constraint about CPU and Memory for background task, but it is very hard for debug. Do you know any way for testing CPU and memory constraints? What is best practice for windows phone 8.1 backgrounds task?

I feel so tired with Background task of windows phone 8.1. Sometime it is ok, some time is none...

Comment: Are you doing anything intensive during the background process? To work on a lower-end phone it will only have 16MB for the background process.  Use plenty of `Debug.Writeline` in your code with error-handling and check the output window in debug mode. In release mode ensure you re-compile the background process as release, and replace the debug dll reference with the release dll and rebuild your solution.  When in release mode, when the background task activates (can take 30 min.) it can write out useful data in the output window so check this, it may help you discover what’s happening.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I only get information from a website and save it to local and create a tile. That all. MSDN says that BackgroundTask is only for 2 second CPU. I dont understand which is 2 seconds? 2 seconds for from all task or ...?

Comment: I've seen that 2 second CPU before, not sure what this means. I believe the background process can run for up to 25 seconds though. If you're just getting text information from a website, then memory won't be an issue. Can you share the code with me?